# Making External JS Files Available in my Meteor App

Tags: javascript, web-applications, meteor

My application file structure is:

app/client/views/view1/view1.html, view1.js

app/public

app/server

And this works fine for my web app, but I am trying to hook in an external (formerly local) javascript tool that I have built (tool1).  In order to do this, I need to make calls to functions in tool1 directory from inside view1.js, specifically so that tool1 can run in the route set in view1.js.

Ive tried putting the tool1 js files in app/public, app/client, and app/client/views/view1, to no avail (Im getting *Uncaught ReferenceError: "object" is not defined*)

If I literally copy and paste the tool1 js files into the view1.js file, then I achieve the functionality I want, but that is not scalable and I dont deem it a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I created a directory `client/compatibility` and that front-loads my js files on application startup